# chef bootstrap with out domain ip

Tags: chef-infra, winrm

I find that if I try and bootstrap a windows 2012 server I get this error.

`knife bootstrap windows winrm 192.0.2.0 -N foobar -x vagrant -P vagrant -r "role[foo]" -E dev -V`

```
Waiting for remote response before bootstrap.ERROR: Failed to authenticate to 192.0.2.0 as vagrant
Response: WinRM::WinRMAuthorizationError
Hint: Make sure to prefix domain usernames with the correct domain name.
Hint: Local user names should be prefixed with computer name or IP address.
EXAMPLE: my_domain\user_namer
```

The workaround is to include the ip address as part of the user name

`192.0.2.0\vagrant`

```
knife bootstrap windows winrm 192.0.2.0 -N foobar -x 192.0.2.0\vagrant -P vagrant -r "role[foo]" -E dev -V
```

My winrm configuration is created with packer.

```
# https://github.com/mwrock/packer-templates/blob/b46ec4e1c3eafcaa64042f32ceab7de2d3789dba/scripts/package.ps1#L28-L45

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="WinRM-HTTP" dir=in localport=5985 protocol=TCP action=allow

$enableArgs=@{Force=$true}
try {
 $command=Get-Command Enable-PSRemoting
  if($command.Parameters.Keys -contains "skipnetworkprofilecheck"){
      $enableArgs.skipnetworkprofilecheck=$true
  }
}
catch {
  $global:error.RemoveAt(0)
}
Enable-PSRemoting @enableArgs
winrm set winrm/config/client/auth '@{Basic="true"}'
winrm set winrm/config/service/auth '@{Basic="true"}'
winrm set winrm/config/service '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
```

Why can I only bootstrap with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, I've discovered `Enable-PSRemoting` and `winrm quickconfig` aren't equivalent commands like I assumed they were.

Adding the following 2 lines to the winrm setup fixes the problem. Bootstrap now no longer requires using the ip address as the name.

```
winrm quickconfig -q
winrm quickconfig -transport:http
```

Full config

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="WinRM-HTTP" dir=in localport=5985 protocol=TCP action=allow
winrm quickconfig -q
winrm quickconfig -transport:http
$enableArgs=@{Force=$true}
try {
 $command=Get-Command Enable-PSRemoting
  if($command.Parameters.Keys -contains "skipnetworkprofilecheck"){
      $enableArgs.skipnetworkprofilecheck=$true
  }
}
catch {
  $global:error.RemoveAt(0)
}
Enable-PSRemoting @enableArgs
#Enable-WSManCredSSP -Force -Role Server #TODO What does this do, do I need it?
winrm set winrm/config/client/auth '@{Basic="true"}'
winrm set winrm/config/service/auth '@{Basic="true"}'
winrm set winrm/config/service '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
```

Note, allowing basic auth and unencrypted winrm is not safe for production use.